# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'ngb-timepicker' is not a known element

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

As just mentioned in ng-bootstrap documentation to define the ng-bootstrap, i just installed in angular-seed project with Angular4 , Bootstrap4. I had included NgbModule.forRoot() in app.module and NgbModule in my another module where i am using the ng-bootstrap component. But still while using the time picker component it gives me this error :

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ngb-timepicker' is not a known element:

If 'ngb-timepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'ngb-timepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("3" style="padding-left: 0px;">
From:
[ERROR ->]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403016/ng2-bootstrap-not-working-in-angular-2-alert-is-not-a-known-element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng2-bootstrap not working in Angular 2 ('alert' is not a known element:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403016/ng2-bootstrap-not-working-in-angular-2-alert-is-not-a-known-element)